# Keyboard goes black if user double taps textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a signup page where there are 3 textfields. The view slides up when a textfield is touched so that the fields are visible with the keyboard showing. However, instead of tapping once, if user quickly taps the textfield twice, the keyboard turns black and the view positioning is irreparably messed up. Here is photo of problem, code is below, thanks in advance[image: ![keyboard is gone, no way to slide the view down to correct position]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7AiV.png)

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        emailTextField.delegate = self
        passwordTextField.delegate = self
        verifyPasswordTextField.delegate = self

        emailTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }


// method to move the view up when keyboard appears
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

       if viewIsLifted == false {

       if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {

                            // hide the logo and name when view slides up
                            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

                               self.likemojiIcon.alpha = 0
                               self.likemojiLabel.alpha = 0

                               }, completion: nil)

                            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                            viewIsLifted = true
                         }
                      }
                   }


                   // method to slide view back down when keyboard is resigned
                   func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

                      if viewIsLifted == true {

                         if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {

                            // make logo and name reappear on slide back down
                            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

                               self.likemojiIcon.alpha = 1
                               self.likemojiLabel.alpha = 1

                               }, completion: nil)

                            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
                            viewIsLifted = false
                         }
                      }
                   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch off user interaction (`beginIgnoringInteractionEvents`) when you're notified that the keyboard *will* appear, and switch it back on (`endIgnoringInteractionEvents`) when you're notified that the keyboard *did* appear.

Answer (score 0):

put the viewIsLifted = true before the animation begins,  otherwise the double tapping could register the keyboard activity twice before the variable is changed, thus crashing.  On a side note,  where is the notification being posting?

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I shifted the order to have viewIsLifted = true before the animation, but it still does the same black keyboard on a quick double tap. Any other ideas?